# Defining a variety over a field extension

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a variety over a perfect field $k$, so we have the structure morphism $\pi:X \rightarrow \mathrm{Spec}\,k$ of finite type.

If $k' \subset k$ is a subfield, then $X$ can be seen as a $k'$-variety if and only if there exists a $k'$-variety $Y$ such that $X \cong Y \times_{k'} k$. Thus it is not necessary that $X$ can be defined over any subfield of $k$. For example, if $X$ is the (affine) elliptic curve given by $y^2 = x^3 + \sqrt{5}x + 6$, then $X$ is defined over $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5})$ but clearly not over $\mathbb{Q}$.

However, by the above example, it seems to me that $X$ can be defined over any **field extension** of $L$ of $k$. But if this is true, then the structure morphism $\pi$ would have to factor through $\mathrm{Spec}\, L$. Is this true? If so, how do we justify this factorization? If not, which part of my reasoning is flawed?

Comment: Why do you think $X$ can be defined over a field extension of $k$? This is completely unjustified.

Comment: @KReiser I was viewing *to be defined over a field* $k$ loosely as the defining equations having coefficients in $k$, that way the coefficients will also be contained in any field extension of $k$. But then I realised I cannot justify that $X \rightarrow \mathrm{Spec}\, L$ is of finite type, that's why I was confused.

Comment: If you think of that elliptic curve over, say the field $\Bbb{R}$, then you are really looking at $X\times_{\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt5)}\Bbb{R}$. That is, the variety you get by extending the scalars. Surely you can show that to be of finite type over $\operatorname{Spec} \Bbb{R}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Careful - viewing "$X$ defined over $k$" as equivalent to "$X$ has equations with coefficients in $k$" misses out on an important part of $X$: where the solutions to the equations live! For instance, trying to define a variety $X\subset\Bbb A^n_k$ with equations in $k$ over an extension $L\supset k$ should get you to $X_L \subset \Bbb A^n_L$. Once you do this, sure enough you get a map $X_L\to \operatorname{Spec} L$. (There's a reason why "coefficients of equations" is only loosely the definition here.)

Comment: So we still have to consider base change after all. I guess we can say it makes *zero sense* to even talk about $X$ being *defined over* $L$!